# laravel socialite not working on live server, only works on local machine

Tags: laravel, exception, google-oauth, laravel-5.8, laravel-socialite

I have recently moved my application into a live server. 
The problem is laravel socialite stopped working, below is the explanation: 
I click on google login and after choosing email, on callback this happens:
`InvalidStateException on Abstract.php on line 200.` 
To fixed this issue i used `stateless()` and now the new error is : 
`` Client error: `POST https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token` resulted in a `400 Bad Request`  response: { "error": "invalid_request", "error_description": "Missing required parameter: code" } ``

Here is the list of things i have already tried:
1- In Google website, I updated google api `url` and `callback url` to new live domain addresses:
`http://www.domain-name.com` and `http://www.domain-name.com/login/google/callback`

2- I have modified config/session.php file like this:
   `'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'www.domain-name.com'),`

3- My storage folder is already have permission like this: 
`drwxrwxr-x  5 root www-data   4096 Jun 24 18:30 storage`

4- I changed `vendor\laravel\socialite\src\Two\GoogleProvider.php` file and removed 'profile' and now it looks like this:

```
protected $scopes = [
'openid',
'email',
];
```

5- I used `php artisan cache:clear` , `composer dump-autoload`, and cleared browser cache data many times.

6- I tried `$userSocial = Socialite::with('google')->user();` instead of `$userSocial = Socialite::driver('google')->user();` , and i still get `InvalidStateException on Abstract.php on line 200`. only when i change to `$userSocial = Socialite::driver('google')->stateless()->user();` the error changes to what i said at the beginning of the question.

my `config/services.php` file is like this:

```
'google' => [
    'client_id' => 'my-correct-client-id-from-google',
    'client_secret' => 'my-correct-client-secret-from-google',
    'redirect' => 'http://www.domain-name.com/login/google/callback',
],
```

I have been trying to fix this for 2 days now. any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate? In production, Google may only provide a code to a HTTPS endpoint to avoid it being intercepted.

Comment: really?! that never came into my head... No i don't have a SSL certificate yet. hope this works.

Comment: it was not the SSL certificate problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after many hours wasted. finally found the answer: 
it was nginx: 
so i ran `sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

and fixed this line:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?query_string; // wrong
```

to

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string; // fixed
```

Comment: Perfect answer!! Thanks a lot!! Got it resolved after a few dirty hours of search :)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Pooria Honarmand
after hours of spend I found same cause you have mentioned.
As I cant change in default config.

Alternatively you can set params like:

```
$urlArr=parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
parse_str($urlArr['query'], $output);
$request->merge($output);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue i spent more then two days today i updated my composer and remove my vendor folder and install the composer again and the issues has been solved